# sendRequest does not seem to use Headers values I specify in the Test

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using sendRequest function to send a 2nd request as part of the Test for my 1st request. But it seems that sendRequest does not use the Headers I specify in the function. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Here is part of my Test, that sends 2nd request:

```
var runHost = pm.environment.get("MyHost");
var runToken = pm.environment.get("Token");
pm.sendRequest({
    url: runHost,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Auth "+runToken,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Here is what I see as an actual Request Headers sent (what I see in Console):

```
PUT https://some_url
Request Headers:
     Content-Type:"text/plain"
     User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
     Accept:"*/*"
     Cache-Control:"no-cache"
     Postman-Token:"5e3543c-1ww0-dfc4-bert-92ba9a455667"
     Host:"my_host"
     Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
     Content-Length:1876
     Connection:"keep-alive"
```

I expect Request Headers to have the following attributes and values:

```
Authorization:"Auth current_token_value"
Accept:"application/json"
Content-Type:"application/json"
...
```

Comment: Have you tried `header` rather than `headers`?

Comment: Thanks @Danny Dainton, that did the trick!

Comment: No worries. If you add the solution as the answer, then you can close this question out. :)

Comment: Can you pls do it (answer it)? :) I think it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key for the object that contains the Request Headers should be `header`, like in the example below:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: runHost,
    method: 'PUT',
    *header*: {
        "Authorization": "Auth "+runToken,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: The same issue. Header is specified correctly. Postman overwrites Header completely (unexpected), while leaves the body untouched (expected).  Reproducing on the public helloworld Postman sample didn't produce the results, as everything there works fine. Seems like there are some cases where it won't take into account the headers set within  pm.sendRequest

Comment: It's probably worth creating your own question that includes all the details for your context.